# How to change the default folder that opens when I add subtitles in VLC mediaplayer?

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, subtitles

Whenever I click on the add subtitles option, it always opens up in C drive. The file that I require is buried deep inside another drive and I do not wish to move them from there. **Can I change the default directory that it opens?** It doesnt even remember the last/frequently visited folder too. The "open a new video file" does remember last visited folder though.

Is there a way out?

Comment: If there is no way out, someone can suggest me an alternate media player too.

Comment: We don't do software recommendations here.

Comment: I know and thats why its not the primary question. _sigh_

Comment: I know and that's why I didn't vote to close your primary question.

Comment: My VLC opens the video location directory when adding subtitles ...

Comment: @DavidPostill Did you tweak with some settings?

Comment: No tweaking ...

Answer (score 3):

#### How do I configure the default folder that opens when adding subtitles?

You can set the **Subtitle auto-detection path**

- Goto `Tools` > `Preferences` > `All` > `Subtitles / OSD` > `Subtitle auto-detection path`.

By default this is set to `.\subtitles, .\subs`.

You can add another path here for your subtitles and they will be auto detected.

[image]