# how to get vlc to open movie folder for subtitles

Tags: vlc-media-player, subtitles

Whevever I would go to the subtitles menu item to add subtitles, it would open in the same folder where my video came from. Now it is not doing that. Either opening c: drive, or the folder for the prior video that I used.  How do I configure so it always open in the same folder that the playing movie is in?
Windows 10. thanks

Comment: Have you tried my answer in [video - How to change the default folder that opens when I add subtitles in VLC mediaplayer? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/923925/how-to-change-the-default-folder-that-opens-when-i-add-subtitles-in-vlc-mediapla)?

Comment: It use to do this, recent updates have broken this function.

Comment: I am sorry, I missed the emails indicating replies. thank you both, i am not sure how to reply directly to each of you.  David,  yes I saw that post before but it is very different. I don't put the subtitles in one folder, i keep them with the movie, so it is different for each movie.  That way I can archive the movies with their subtitles.

Comment: Moab, thank you  I was afraid of that since I could not find a solution. But I am also surprised I did not find other people complaining about it.  I guess I missed it. I would assume vlc is working on  a fix.